# How to reduce graviation on single object?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, physics

I want to know how to make object's gravitation low(something like 1.0) or turn it off at all when actuator gives positive pulse. It should keep dynamics, evrything should stay as it is except it shouldn't go down so fast(note so it has also a control that makes it to move on Z axis using linear velocity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! Again, I recieved answer and I can tell it myself:
Using constraint actuator with Damping bigger than 1(about 0.25), distance 1000 and -Z axis I achieved this result!:)